# JSESSIONID changes without any request

Tags: java, spring-boot, session-cookies

I'm using Spring boot. And it occurs in https protocol.

When I access to the website, the JSESSION cookie is created.

After page loaded, when I refresh the `Developer tools > Application > Cookies` the JSESSION cookie is changed to something else without any request or redirection.

It sometimes happen, but not always.

When I use chrome's secret mode or delete chrome browsing history, it doesn't happen.

I added `SameSite=None; Secure;` to JSESSION cookie, but it didn't work.

What do I have to do?

Answer (score 2):

Spring Security changes the session id, before you are authenticated, to another session id, after you are authenticated. That's done to prevent the "session fixation attack"

- [OWASP Session fixation](https://owasp.org/www-community/attacks/Session_fixation)
- [WIKI Session fixation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Session_fixation)
- [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122086/can-you-give-me-an-example-of-a-session-fixation-attack)

Comment: Can it cause difference between http localhost and https server?

Comment: And if spring security changes JSESSIONID after login, it should always happen. But it happens randomly..

Comment: Show us your spring-security configuration, maybe we then can help you. Also include a minimum example to reproduce the problem.

Comment: I think I don't have any spring-security related configuration

Comment: Your answer were not my solution, but thank you for increasing my knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

The problem were not in my Spring boot application.

The Nginx server had two different web application on same domain.

And their JSESSIONID cookie path were same `('/')`.

Other web application overwrote my web application's JSESSIONID cookie.

So I asked to change Nginx config(Probably it was proxy config).